# How can you use circular #import to strongly typed objects in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pointers, scope

How can you use circular #import to strongly typed objects in objective-c

I have an audio controller class, a menu class and a gameview class.

The application delegate sets up these classes and assigns a pointers so:

the menu class is aware of the audio and gameview class
the gameview class has a reference to the audio and menu class

I am using NSObject for the reference to the gameview class from the menu class. This is because the menu class has a reference to the gameview class and has a #import gameview.h declaration. The code won't compile with circular #import

Suggestions please :) ?

```
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController {

    NSObject *gameref; // weak type here to avoid include of gameview above
    AudioController *audioref;

}
```

and...

```
#import "AudioController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

    @interface GameViewController : UIViewController {

        MenuViewController *menuref;
        AudioController *audioref;

    }
```

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting? Also, `id` is the more standard universal type. In this case, you should do as jib suggests rather than using `id` or `NSObject *`.

Comment: I was getting a compiler warning due to the loose typing of gameref as an NSObject instead of a gameviewcontroller when calling a method on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fisrt, in your .h file use

```
@class GameViewController, AudioController
```

and

```
@class AudioController, MenuViewController
```

in your .m file use

```
#import "GameViewController"
#import "AudioController"
```

and

```
#import "AudioController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"
```

There is no 'circular reference' problem.
Second, using NSObject instead of the actual classname isn't in any way a weak reference. Also, if you mean #include say #include. If you mean #import, say #import.

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you got what I meant. No more compiler warnings YAY :)